# Error: Unable to resolve module http from ../node_modules/micro-ftch/index.js: http could not be found within the project or in these directories:

Tags: react-native

node_modules
52 | function fetchNode(url, _options) {
53 |     let options = { ...DEFAULT_OPT, ..._options };

> 54 |     const http = require('http');
> |                           ^
> 55 |     const https = require('https');
> 56 |     const zlib = require('zlib');
> 57 |     const { promisify } = require('util');
> at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (../node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:139:15)
> at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (../node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:277:43)
> at Object.resolve (../node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:169:21)
> at Graph._resolveDependencies (../node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:472:35)
> at Graph._processModule (../node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:260:38)
> at async Graph._addDependency (../node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:371:20)
> at async Promise.all (index 1)
> at async Graph._processModule (../node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:321:5)
> at async Graph._addDependency (../node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:371:20)
> at async Promise.all (index 12)

I have already added mapping in package.json

"react-native": {
"http": "@tradle/react-native-http",
"https": "https-browserify"
},
"browser": {
"http": "@tradle/react-native-http",
"https": "https-browserify"
}

Comment: Did you figure this out?